# Detecting .com / .co.uk etc etc

Tags: php, url, preg-match, detection

I currently have a preg_match to detect http:// and www. etc..... but I want to detect domain.com or domain.co.uk from a string

> example string: "Hey hows it going,
>   check out domain.com" And I want to
>   detect domain.com

What I want is to detect any major domains form this string i.e. .com .co.uk .eu etc... from the form example.com example2.co.uk and then return true or false to handle it. In this case it would find domain.com.

However I do NOT want it to detect something like:

> "hey.i love this site"

Whereby this is obviously an error in typing a space from the full stop!

Any ideas i need to scratch up on my regex!

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: @Stefan re your update, even if you are detecting URLs in a string, I would recommend to fetch the whole thing and then do a `parse_url()` on it (instead of using regexes to separate the URL into hostname, domain, subdomain...) if you do need a regex, why not add some example HTML that you would want to extract it from.

Comment: It would be something along the lines of "Yeh i agreed google.com " and then detecting the google.com

Comment: @Stefan aahh, I see. That's not going to be trivial I think. Are you fine with detecting any xxx.yyy combination or really just valid domains?

Comment: @Pekka - Hmmm good question If someone typed example: "hey hows it going.i love this site" it would then detect it... correct? Well in that case yes detect all known major valid domains i.e .com's .co.uk .eu etc etc would be ideal :)

Comment: @Stefan I'll delete my answer to clear the way for new ones, but please add a more clear example to your question (essentially, a summary of our conversation here in the comments) so people understand what it is about.

Comment: @Pekka - still relatively new here! :) No problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After they introduced non-Latin urls, it will be close to impossible to use regex to get a completely working filter. So I'd say it's not even worth trying to use regex for this anymore. Doubt parse_url() has support for it yet either, but using it means someone else have to work out the problems with non-Latin urls, which is always a bonus :) So use that

http://au.php.net/parse_url

http://thenextweb.com/me/2010/05/06/monumental-day-internet-nonlatin-domain-names-live/

Edit: 
Ok, from a string, split it into words like this

```
$array = explode(" ", $string);

for(int i = 0; i < count($array);i++)
{
  if(parse_url($array[i]) != false)
  {
    $url[] = $array[i];
  }
}
```

Ok, parse_url() isn't supposed to be used like this, but there is no other function built into php to do url filtering as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Here is regexp that would match a provided list of domain zones:

```
[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|co\.uk|net|org)
```